# External Table Help - Problem with FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' if additional comma exists in a value in the field

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I have a comma delimited txt file and I am using an external table to load the data down below:

```
create table test_ext_table
     CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER, 
     CUSTOMER_NAME       VARCHAR2(255),  
     CUSTOMER_NUMBER     NUMBER)  
     ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( type oracle_loader 
      default directory TXT_DIR 
      access parameters 
      (RECORDS delimited by newline SKIP 1 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       LRTRIM 
       MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
      ) 
      LOCATION (TEST.txt)
      )
      REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED);
```

I know the external table recognizes each field terminated by a comma, but let's say in the text file I have the following

TEST.txt

```
customer_id, customer_name, customer_number
1,a,10
2,b,11
3,c,12
4,Hello, Inc,13
```

For the 4 row in the txt file, because there is an additional ',' in the customer_name field, the external table isn't able to properly read the customer name into the table. Is there a way for me to adjust the external table so that it ignores additional ',' or any special characters?

Comment: How should the DBMS guess which comma is right and which is wrong? If commas appear in the text, then a comma is just not an appropriate delimiter. Choose another.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are 2 ways to do that:

- optionally enclose string into e.g. double quotes
- change delimiter from comma to something else, e.g. semi-colon

Otherwise, there's no way to leave it "as is" and make Oracle recognize which comma represents what.